# Drawing on HTML canvas which is rotating

Tags: html5-canvas, drawing

I have a requirement of drawing on a rotating canvas. The HTML canvas is rotating infinitely at a certain speed. When i use the below code i am able to draw but this is not what i was looking for. In real life when you just hold a pen on a rotating object a circle is drawn, i am looking for the same thing here. I have tried many libraries but it did not work

```js
var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
        prevX = 0,
        currX = 0,
        prevY = 0,
        currY = 0,
        dot_flag = false;

    var x = "black",
        y = 2;
    
    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('can');
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = canvas.width;
        h = canvas.height;
    
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            findxy('move', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            findxy('down', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            findxy('up', e)
        }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
            findxy('out', e)
        }, false);
    }
    
    function color(obj) {
        switch (obj.id) {
            case "green":
                x = "green";
                break;
            case "blue":
                x = "blue";
                break;
            case "red":
                x = "red";
                break;
            case "yellow":
                x = "yellow";
                break;
            case "orange":
                x = "orange";
                break;
            case "black":
                x = "black";
                break;
            case "white":
                x = "white";
                break;
        }
        if (x == "white") y = 14;
        else y = 2;
    
    }
    
    function draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    
    function erase() {
        var m = confirm("Want to clear");
        if (m) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    
    function save() {
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
    }
    
    function findxy(res, e) {
        if (res == 'down') {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
    
            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            if (dot_flag) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
            flag = false;
        }
        if (res == 'move') {
            if (flag) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                draw();
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes rotating /* Safari and Chrome */ {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.rotating {
  animation: rotating 1.5s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
        <canvas class="rotating" id="can" width="400" height="400" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:2px solid;border-radius:50%;"></canvas>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:12%;left:43%;">Choose Color</div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:45%;width:10px;height:10px;background:green;" id="green" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:46%;width:10px;height:10px;background:blue;" id="blue" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:15%;left:47%;width:10px;height:10px;background:red;" id="red" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:45%;width:10px;height:10px;background:yellow;" id="yellow" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:46%;width:10px;height:10px;background:orange;" id="orange" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:17%;left:47%;width:10px;height:10px;background:black;" id="black" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:20%;left:43%;">Eraser</div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:22%;left:45%;width:15px;height:15px;background:white;border:2px solid;" id="white" onclick="color(this)"></div>
        <img id="canvasimg" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:52%;" style="display:none;">
        <input type="button" value="save" id="btn" size="30" onclick="save()" style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:10%;">
        <input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" onclick="erase()" style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:15%;">
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rotating the canvas using a CSS animation, but the drawing is all in JS, your canvas does not "know" that it has been rotated, we will need to get the style of the canvas to get the transform matrix and with that we can get the current angle.

Best to show you with an example, see what I added in your `function draw`

I simplified a lot of your code to just focus on getting the angle, this does not do the drawing for you but it is a push in the right direction, this problem feel like a school homework so you should be able to take the rest of the way.

```js
var canvas, ctx, st, prevX = 0, currX = 0, prevY = 0, currY = 0

function draw() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
  ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
  ctx.stroke();

  var matrix = st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
    st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
    st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
    st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
    st.getPropertyValue("transform")

  var values = matrix.split('(')[1];
  values = values.split(')')[0];
  values = values.split(',');
  var a = values[0];
  var b = values[1];
  var angle = Math.atan2(b, a)
  console.log("angle =", angle)
}

function findxy(e) {
  prevX = currX;
  prevY = currY;
  currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
  draw();
}

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('can');
  st = window.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke()
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", findxy);
}
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.rotating {
  animation: rotating 5s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
  <canvas class="rotating" id="can" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Helder how can i contact you? i would like to discuss if you would be interested to create (paid) the project for me.

Comment: @SachinGiri you can try some sites like: https://www.guru.com/, https://www.freelancer.com/